# Using automapper works fine for me if using single entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-5.0

If I am adding two or more entities, I must declare all the properties in a single class in order to properly map them to the JS from the View in the Ajax call.

**Just checking to see if I'm missing something that AutoMapper can do that I'm not utilizing...**

For instance, if using just one entity (Customer), the following in AutoMapper works fine:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDTO, Customer>();
                    var customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerDTO, Customer>(custDTO);
```

If using two or more entities, I must do the following:

```
using (var dbcxtTrans = DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.Address1 = custProjDTO.customer_Address1;
    cust.Address2 = custProjDTO.customer_Address2;
    cust.CellPhone = custProjDTO.customer_CellPhone;
    cust.City = custProjDTO.customer_City;
    cust.Company = custProjDTO.customer_Company;
    cust.CreatedDate = custProjDTO.customer_CreatedDate;
    cust.Email = custProjDTO.customer_Email;
    cust.FirstName = custProjDTO.customer_FirstName;
    cust.HomePhone = custProjDTO.customer_HomePhone;
    cust.IMAddress = custProjDTO.customer_IMAddress;
    cust.LastName = custProjDTO.customer_LastName;
    cust.State = custProjDTO.customer_State;
    cust.UpdatedDate = custProjDTO.customer_UpdatedDate;
    cust.UserName = custProjDTO.customer_UserName;
    cust.Website = custProjDTO.customer_Website;
    cust.Zip = custProjDTO.customer_Zip;

    DbContext.Customers.Add(cust);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    Project proj = new Project();
    proj.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID;
    proj.CategoryID = custProjDTO.project_CategoryID;
    proj.CreatedDate = custProjDTO.project_CreatedDate;
    proj.Description = custProjDTO.project_Description;
    proj.Name = custProjDTO.project_Name;
    proj.Notes = custProjDTO.project_Notes;
    proj.PriorityID = custProjDTO.project_PriorityID;
    proj.Quote = custProjDTO.project_Quote;
    proj.StatusID = custProjDTO.project_StatusID;
    proj.UpdatedDate = custProjDTO.project_UpdatedDate;

    DbContext.Projects.Add(proj);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    dbcxtTrans.Commit();
}
```

This is because my property names must align with the names in the View (see below)

```
@model YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerProject

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer & Project";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<div class="body-content">
    <h4>Customer/Project</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "UserName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Last Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address1" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Address2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address2" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Address2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "City" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "State" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Zip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Zip" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Zip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_HomePhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Home Phone" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_HomePhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_CellPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Cell Phone" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_CellPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Website" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_Website, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_IMAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "IM Address" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_IMAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ProjectName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project_CategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryDescription"), "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project_PriorityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Priorities, "PriorityID", "PriorityDescription"), "-- Select Priority --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_PriorityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.project_StatusID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Statuses, "StatusID", "StatusDescription"), "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_StatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project_Quote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Quote" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_Quote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project_Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Notes" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project_Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnCustomerProjectCreate" class="btn btn-default col-offset-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    @Html.Hidden("customerprojectCreateUrl", Url.Action("Create", "CustomerProjects", new { area = "Customers" }))
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            if (typeof contentCreateCustomerProject == "function")
                contentCreateCustomerProject();
        });
    </script>
}
```

which, in turn, must align with my JS properties:

```
var customerProject_Input = {
        customer_UserName: $('#customer_UserName').val(),
        customer_Email: $('#customer_Email').val(),
        customer_Company: $('#customer_Company').val(),
        customer_FirstName: $('#customer_FirstName').val(),
        customer_LastName: $('#customer_LastName').val(),
        customer_Address1: $('#customer_Address1').val(),
        customer_Address2: $('#customer_Address2').val(),
        customer_City: $('#customer_City').val(),
        customer_State: $('#customer_State').val(),
        customer_Zip: $('#customer_Zip').val(),
        customer_HomePhone: $('#customer_HomePhone').val(),
        customer_CellPhone: $('#customer_CellPhone').val(),
        customer_Website: $('#customer_Website').val(),
        customer_IMAddress: $('#customer_IMAddress').val(),
        customer_CreatedDate: currdate,
        customer_UpdatedDate: null,
        project_Name: $('#project_Name').val(),
        project_Description: $('#project_Description').val(),
        project_CategoryID: $('#project_CategoryID').val(),
        project_PriorityID: $('#project_PriorityID').val(),
        project_StatusID: $('#project_StatusID').val(),
        project_Quote: $('#project_Quote').val(),
        project_Notes: $('#project_Notes').val(),
        project_CreatedDate: currdate,
        project_UpdatedDate: null
    };
```

which, in turn, can only be defined in **one** class (see below):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CustomerProject
    {
        //Customer    
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short customer_CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Company { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 99999 or 99999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_HomePhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_CellPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_Website { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string customer_IMAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime customer_CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? customer_UpdatedDate { get; set; }


        //Project

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Proj ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_ProjectID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Cust ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_CategoryID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_PriorityID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [DataMember]
        public short project_StatusID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? project_Quote { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string project_Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime project_CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? project_UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your problem, but have you looked into `RecognizePrefixes`/`RecognizeDestinationPrefixes`?

Answer (score 1):

Well as property names are not same in both classes, try creating detailed mapping configuration like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address1, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Address1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address2, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Address2))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CellPhone, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_CellPhone))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.City, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_City))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Company))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDate, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_CreatedDate))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Email))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HomePhone, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_HomePhone))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IMAddress, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_IMAddress))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_LastName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.State, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_State))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDate, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_UpdatedDate))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_UserName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Website, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Website))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Zip, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.customer_Zip));
```

Also, for saving object you don't need to call following twice:

```
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

do it just once:

```
 DbContext.Projects.Add(proj);
 DbContext.Customers.Add(cust);
 await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I like your comment about the await clause, but, the AutoMapper code is essentially the same amount of typing I would do (even more) for what is originally there now...

Comment: btw, I had to use the SaveChanges method twice (one for each entity). Otherwise, I wouldn't have gotten the foreign key for the other entity if the first one wasn't saved.

Comment: well the thing with automapper is that you are using the mapping over and over again in multiple places. Also it keeps your controllers clean as you can have separate bootstraper to register mappings.